# Laravel Binary String Issue When DB:raw and Pluck() or toArray()

Tags: laravel

So when i use retrieve an object using get, i got a normal result

Code:

```
Contact::select(\DB::raw("CONCAT(COALESCE(`name`,''),' ',COALESCE(`last_name`,'')) AS display_name"),'id','name','last_name')->where('id',2382)->get()
```

Result:

```
[
        "display_name" => "OFNA • CASA "
        "id" => 2382
        "name" => "OFNA • CASA"
        "last_name" => null
      ]
```

but if i do a ->pluck() or ->toArray() i got this result:

```
[
    "display_name" => b"Ofna Â€¢ Casa "
    "id" => 2382
    "name" => "OFNA • CASA"
    "last_name" => null
  ]
```

For some reason the display_name is encoding incorrectly when converting to an Array. is there a way to fix this? or is a Laravel issue?

Thanks

My Laravel version is 6.8

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround, but im sure there should be a fix to this issue

This is my work around, map the get and then use the pluck on the collection after the map

```
                 get()->
                 map(function($object){
                    return [
                        'name'=>$object->name.' '.$object->last_name,
                        'id'=>$object->id
                    ];
                })->pluck('name','id');
```

It does work but im sure there should be a better way or maybe report it to Laravel.

Hope someone knows better about this.

THanks